# how to take snapshot of whole-world map on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, apple-maps

I want to take a snapshot using MKMapSnapshotter. It always returns only the portion of the map visible on the screen and not the entire world. I want the snapshot of the entire world map as a flat 2D image.

Setting:

```
mapSnapshotOptions.region = MKCoordinateRegionForMapRect(MKMapRectWorld)
```

does not help either.

Comment: You cannot.  no reason.